# SML val 'a grupper = fn : int -> 'a list -> 'a list list

Tags: list, functional-programming, sml

I wanna create a function that have the type  `int -> 'a list -> 'a list list`

Function call:

`grupper 2 [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]` shall return `[[3, 1], [4, 1], [5, 9]]`

`grupper 4 [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]` shall return `[[3, 1, 4, 1], [5, 9]]`

`grupper 42 [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]` shall return `[[3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]]`.

I got this so far

```
fun grupper _ [] = []
| grupper n (x::xs) = if n > length(x::xs) then [x::xs]
                      else [List.take(x::xs, n)] @ grupper (n) xs
```

some help please.

Comment: You should always avoid using append (@), especially when you are making the first element a list just to append it. Here (as shown by pad) you can just put the element in from of the list returned by `grupper` with the cons operator (::).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use both `List.take` and `List.drop`:

```
fun grupper _ [] = []
  | grupper n xs = if n >= length xs then [xs]
                   else List.take(xs, n)::(grupper n (List.drop(xs, n)))
```